# jQuery pass parameters into function call from ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parameters, callback

I want to call a function when a jQuery Ajax request is successfull. I want to pass a parameter into a second function that apparently (it doesn't work) doesn't exist inside the jquery anonymous function.

Here is my Ajax function:

```
function core_get_title(url,id_of_link){

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "url_handler.php",
                    data: { 
                        url: url,
                        cmd: "get_title",
                        },
                    success: function(data) {
                        core_title_auto(data,id_of_link);
                        }   
                });

            }
```

And when it calls core_title_auto, the id_of_link parameter is empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: check your request with FireBug.

Comment: what is the content of the response?

Comment: check `id_of_link` before invoking ajax

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Why does that matter?

Answer (score 0):

check and see whats in id_of_link before ajax call by placing an alert function

```
function core_get_title(url,id_of_link){
                alert("id_of_link"+id_of_link);  
                $.ajax({
                    /*...... your code */  
                });

            }
```